# Can I use 15V 2A transformer with this circuit?

Tags: transformer, battery-charging, lead-acid

I m trying to build a charger circuit for a **12V 7Ah Sealed Lead Acid Battery**. I found this circuit online and it uses **15V-0-15V 1A** Transformer as AC input.

[Circuit Source](http://www.electronicshub.org/automatic-battery-charger-circuit/)

I have a **15V-0-15V 2A** Transformer and can I use it with this circuit without any modification?

[image]

Comment: The author of this schematic must have been drunk when he made it - there is a 100 ohm resistor in series with the battery (1/2W ie max 70mA before it hits max power!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transformer that rated to supply more current is not usually going to be a problem. The one recommended is 1A and you have a 2A transformer - 2A means it is capable of supplying 2A if the load demands 2A.

As an extra bit of advice, are you aware that the charge current is probably limited to a few tens of mA. Also, the circuit diagram and parts list in the link do not totally match - this always makes me nervous and I would sueest some form of simulation first.

Comment: i saw it now looks like zener diode value listed and in diagram are different. can you suggest any reliable and tested charger circuit please?

Comment: Sorry, I've never had a need to charge a battery with a home made circuit.

Comment: If it's a car battery they usually charge to 14.4V trough the alternator, since this is a home made charger I would suggest a safe 12.6V for charge.